# Difference between $\sqrt[4]{-1}$ and $\sqrt[4]{(-1)^3}$

Tags: complex-numbers

While solving for all $8$ roots of $x^8=1$, I got all the roots as$$\begin{align*} & x=\pm1\\ & x=\pm i\\ & x=\pm\sqrt[4]{-1}\\ & x=\pm (-1)^{3/4}\end{align*}\tag1$$
My only questions is:

> **Question:** What's the difference between $\sqrt[4]{-1}$ and $(-1)^{3/4}$? Evaluating everything, aren't those two roots evidently the same?

I am somewhat confused by this. It seems kind of similar to "What's $\sqrt{-36}\times\sqrt{-9}$" question. In the sense that I don't know which answer is correct and why.

Comment: A better way to express the 8 roots of $x^8 = 1$ would be to say that the roots are $e^{n\pi i/4}$ for $n = 0,1,2,\ldots,7$

Comment: @Frank. Just as a comment. I think it is important first to go into the rules of exponents and under what circumstances these rules can be applied. Same goes for conversion between radical and exponential notation. These rules cannot be applied blindly to negative or complex bases. Likewise, $\sqrt{-36}$ multiplied by $\sqrt{-9}$ is certainly not $\sqrt{324}$, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $\sqrt[4]{-1}$ is not well-defined. There are four complex numbers whose fourth powers are $-1$, namely 
$$
\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2},\quad\frac{1-i}{\sqrt2},\quad\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt2},\quad\frac{-1-i}{\sqrt2}.
$$
These, along with $\pm1$ and $\pm i$ are the eighth roots of $1$ that you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have "solved" using Wolfram Alpha.

And probably what they understand by $\sqrt[4]{-1}$ is $\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}$

And probably what they understand by $(-1)^{3/4}$ is $(\sqrt[4]{-1})^3$ which would be $\cos\frac{3\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{3\pi}{4}$

Conclusion: You shouldn't blindly trust any software. I can give you examples of integrals where Wolfram Alpha returns wrong results or fails to evaluate it alltogether.

Comment: Shouldn't they fix that? Also, I solved $x^8=1$ by difference of squares, and equated the remaining factors to zero.

Comment: @Frank There is nothing for them to fix. WA *defines* fractional powers of negative reals like $(-1)^{3/4}$ to be the *principal value*. Morale IMHO is that when using math software, make sure to understand their rules, first.